# How to prevent docker image update (best practice)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running my home wifi controller (TP-Link Omada) from a docker image in a local linux server. Unfortunately, the image was updated and the new controller version does not appear to recognize my exiting "site" / devices. The wireless access points and switch are all still working in stand-alone mode with their settings, but I can't touch/change anything until I re-adopt them into a new site I generate with the "new" controller.

I would like to prevent images from updating in the future or at the very least having a way to revert if they break like this again. What would be a good way to prevent this from happening? Here is a snippet from my docker-compose

```yaml
# Omada Controller for TP-Link switches and APs
omada-controller:
  container_name: omada-controller
  image: mbentley/omada-controller
  restart: unless-stopped
  environment:
    - TZ=$TZ
  volumes:
    - $DOCKERDIR/apps/omada/data:/opt/tplink/EAPController/data'
    - $DOCKERDIR/apps/omada/work:/opt/tplink/EAPController/work'
    - $DOCKERDIR/apps/omada/logs:/opt/tplink/EAPController/logs'
  networks:
    - t2_proxy
  security_opt:
    - no-new-privileges:true
  ports:
    - '8088:8088'
    - '$OMADA_PORT:8043'
    - '27001:27001/udp'
    - '27002:27002'
    - '27017:27017'
    - '29810:29810/udp'
    - '29811:29811'
    - '29812:29812'
    - '29813:29813'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you dont use a tag for the image, than docker uses the `latest` tag. Almost always this refers to to newest version. Just use a defined tagged version of the  image. You can find the available tags for `mbentley/omada-controller` [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/mbentley/omada-controller/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated).
So if you want to use the 4.1 version, than that part in the compose file should be:

```
 image: mbentley/omada-controller:4.1
```

That said, normally it shouldn't magically update the image itself. It only gets updated if you start your container and the tagged image isn't available locally. Or you run `docker-compose pull` to force a pull of the images specified in the compose file.